# Is it possible to disable/set color for click effect on a List view cell?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Each box in the below image is a list view item, when i press anywhere in one of them, an orange background is added to it, i assume there is some background color set based on tap
but i cant find it anywhere to change it
Still learning Xamarin, any help is appreciated!

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSDl1.jpg

```
<ListView x:FieldModifier="internal" x:Name="planItemsView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" ItemSelected="planItemsView_ItemSelected">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame>// Code </Frame>

                <StackLayout>// Code </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix:
Adding
`<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>`
to styles.xml fixed the orange color effect.
however, there is still a click effect but it isn't a big deal!

The discussion where i got the answer from:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4447

Comment: accept your answer so more people can find this beneficial

Comment: there is 2 day gap from accepting my own answer. 12 hours to go

Comment: Your solution will address behaviour on Android only, is that what you want? Presumably you ate happy with the behaviour on the other platforms?

Comment: If you are not bothered about being able to tap the cell at all in your list view you can always set IsEnabled to false on the DataTemplate cell. That should disable the tap gesture completely?

Comment: I am not working on iOS at the moment. 

would setting IsEnabled to false affect contents inside the view cell ? Which is being changed at times. 
so would that prevent changes from being applied ?